# Creating a maximum digraph path from two lists

Tags: python-3.x, graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

Lets say you have two lists u and v such that:

```
u  v
6  4
0  1
0  3
1  2
2  3
3  0
4  2
```

...in which u is the beginning of an edge, and v is its end. The number 6 represents the number of edges, and 4 represents the number of nodes. Following the first 0 in the u list, you see that u points to v such that 0 points to 1, and 0 points to 3. You can continue the process to see that 1 then points to 2, and then to 3, giving you [0,1,2,3]. Alternatively, following the other 0, 0 points to 3, which points to 2, giving you[0,3,2]

```
Answer = [ [0,1,2,3], [0,3,2] ]
```

Any thoughts on how I can approach this? It seems relatively easy but I have not been able to find a good solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical problem in graph theory known as the [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). It is NP-hard, since it is at least as hard as the NP-complete [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) which asks for a path visiting every vertex. Therefore, there is no known algorithm which both gives exact solutions (i.e. the true longest path) while also scaling efficiently to large instances of the problem.

If you need exact solutions, then you won't be able to do much better than some kind of [backtracking search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). Otherwise, if approximate solutions are "good enough" for your use-case, then there are some heuristic algorithms but they aren't very good; given standard assumptions about problem hardness, there is no efficient approximation algorithm which consistently finds a path of length proportional to n^c when one exists, for any constant c > 0. [Says Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Approximation):

> In the case of unweighted but directed graphs, strong inapproximability results are known. For every e > 0 the problem cannot be approximated to within a factor of n^(1 - e) unless P = NP, and with stronger complexity-theoretic assumptions it cannot be approximated to within a factor of n / (log n)^(2 + e). The color-coding technique can be used to find paths of logarithmic length, if they exist, but this gives an approximation ratio of only O(n / log n).